# How do i allow user change application background color in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do i allow user change application color in ionic using Angular. E.G, i want to create a button that when it is clicked it should bring a drop down of colors and when a color is selected it should change the application background color

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$ionicPopup`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).

Add `ng-click="selectTheme()"` to your button, and declare it like:

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.selectTheme = function() {
        $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Select Theme',
            templateUrl: 'templates/select-theme.html',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [{ text: 'Ok' }],
        });
    });
    $scope.themes = [
        { name: 'Theme 1', color: '#f00' },
        { name: 'Theme 2', color: '#0f0' },
        { name: 'Theme 3', color: '#00f' },
        { name: 'Theme 4', color: '#ff0' },
        { name: 'Theme 5', color: '#0ff' },
    ];
    $scope.changeTheme = function (theme) {
        $scope.bgColor = theme;
    };
    $scope.bgColor = $scope.themes[0]; // initial theme
})
```

Then you can create a list to choose colors in `templates/select-theme.html`:

```
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="theme in themes" ng-click="changeTheme(theme)">
        <div class="color-ball" style="background-color:{{theme.color}}"></div>
        <h2 ng-bind="theme.name"></h2>
        <p ng-if="theme === bgColor">(Selected)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add your styles:

```
.color-ball {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Then, you just need to set `style="background-color:{{bgColor.color}}"` in your `<body>`, ...

Hope it helps.